# Key down and up events doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyD);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyU);
function keyD(e){

    if(e.keycode == 38){
        plat1UpP = true;
    }else if(e.keycode == 40){
        plat1DownP = true;
    }
}

function keyU(e){
    if(e.keycode == 38){
        plat1UpP = false;
    }else if(e.keycode == 40){
        plat1DownP = false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a pong game in html5, javascript and css with canvas, but the events for keydown and keyup don't work.

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't receive the keydown/keyup.

Comment: Have you tried adding a console.log statement to make sure that it doesn't run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change `keycode` to `keyCode`.

> consider some browsers doesn't support `keyCode` and you must use
>   `which`.

Change your code to this, **it will work for all of them.**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyD);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyU);
function keyD(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key  == 38){
        plat1UpP = true;
    }else if(key == 40){
        plat1DownP = true;
    }
}

function keyU(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key ){
        plat1UpP = false;
    }else if(key){
        plat1DownP = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error, you new to use `e.keyCode` insted of `e.keycode`.